# C# Catch OracleException vs General Exception

Tags: c#, oracle, try-catch

I'm updating code from a prior project.  I want to catch any issues in the SQL commands, so I put an "X" at the beginning of the SQL query.  In Microsoft, usually the SqlException will catch such issues.  In the code below, I'm getting the general Exception and not the OracleException. Do I have the proper exception, and if so why is not firing?

```
public static string getSKUByPONumber(string poNumber)
{
    Logging.logMethodStart("getSKUByPONumber poNumber=" + poNumber);

    string rt = "";
    string sql = "x select i.segment1 || '.' || i.segment2 " +
                 " from po_headers_all h " +
                 " inner join po.po_lines_all l on( h.po_header_id = l.po_header_id ) " +
                 " inner join inv.mtl_system_items_b i on( l.item_id = i.inventory_item_id ) " +
                 " where h.segment1 = '" + poNumber.Trim() + "'";

    try
    {
        rt = getOracleSingleValue(sql);
    }
    catch (OracleException ex)
    {
        string errMsg = "OracleException: getSKUByPONumber failed with error code: " + ex.Message + " Sql=" + sql;
        Logging.logHelperError("getSKUByPONumber", ex.Message);
        Logging.TraceWriteLine(errMsg); 
        throw new Exception(errMsg);
    }
    catch (Exception ex)
    {
        Logging.logHelperError("getSKUByPONumber", ex.Message);
        throw new Exception("getSKUByPONumber failed with error code: " + ex.Message + " Sql=" + sql );
    }

    Logging.logMethodEnd("getSKUByPONumber poNumber=" + poNumber + " sku=" + rt);
    return rt;
}
```

Revised code:

```
    public static string getOracleSingleValue(string sql)
    {
        OracleConnection conn = Config.GetOracleSqlconnection();
        string rt = "";

        try
        {
            DataSet ds = new DataSet();
            OracleDataAdapter adapter = new OracleDataAdapter(sql, conn);
            OracleCommandBuilder builder = new OracleCommandBuilder(adapter);

            adapter.Fill(ds, "data");

            if (ds.Tables["data"].Rows.Count > 0)
            {
                DataRow row = ds.Tables["data"].Rows[0];
                rt = row[0].ToString();
            }
        }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            Logging.logHelperError("getOracleSingleValue: SqlException:", ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("getOracleSingleValue failed with SqlException: " + ex.Message);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            Logging.logHelperError("getOracleSingleValue", ex.Message);
            throw new Exception("getOracleSingleValue failed with error code: " + ex.Message);
        }
        finally
        {
            conn.Close();
            conn.Dispose();
        }

        return rt;
    }



public static string getSKUByPONumber(string poNumber)
{
    Logging.logMethodStart("getSKUByPONumber poNumber=" + poNumber);

    string rt = "";
    string sql = "x select i.segment1 || '.' || i.segment2 " +
                 " from po_headers_all h " +
                 " inner join po.po_lines_all l on( h.po_header_id = l.po_header_id ) " +
                 " inner join inv.mtl_system_items_b i on( l.item_id = i.inventory_item_id ) " +
                 " where h.segment1 = '" + poNumber.Trim() + "'";

    try
    {
        rt = getOracleSingleValue(sql);
    }
        catch (SqlException ex)
        {
            string errMsg = "SqlException: getDropShipFlag failed with error code: " + ex.Message + " sql=" + sql;
            Logging.TraceWriteLine(errMsg);
            Logging.logHelperError("getDropShipFlag", ex.Message);
            throw new Exception(errMsg);
        }
        catch (Exception ex)
        {
            string innerExMessage = ""; 
            if (ex.InnerException != null)
            {
                innerExMessage = ex.Message + " Internal Exception:" + ex.InnerException; 
            }
            Logging.logHelperError("getDropShipFlag", ex.Message + innerExMessage);
            throw new Exception("Exception: getDropShipFlag failed with error code: " + ex.Message);
        }

    Logging.logMethodEnd("getSKUByPONumber poNumber=" + poNumber + " sku=" + rt);
    return rt;
}
```

Final error is:

> {"Exception: getSKUByPONumberfailed with error code:
>   getOracleSingleValue failed with error code: ORA-00900: invalid SQL
>   statement"}

Comment: Did you debug this and see the type of the exception being thrown at runtime?

Comment: Added that code, and put SqlException in it  too, see reply to answer below.

Comment: Can you please check what I changed in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that you are calling a routine of your own getOracleSingleValue(). 
This routine has to throw an exception for you to catch any exceptions.
This looks like a custom (non Oracle) function I suspect.
Check that.

Comment: Good point, I added that routine above to my question, after adding the SqlException there, then adding the internal exception in the second routine. 
Run debugger, the getOracleSingleValue also gets the general exception instead of the SqlException though.

Comment: Can you please check what I changed in the question?

Comment: Post the code of getOracleSingleValue() where you are throwing the exception. As far as I can see you are catching a problem in your SQL statement.

Comment: Yes, I put the "X" at the beginning of my SQL statement to force it to cause the error, so I could check the exception handling.  I've used this pattern to catch errors in MS/SQL and show the SQL in the SQLException catch.

Comment: getOracleSingleValue is the one that has access to the OracleException, not getSKUByPONumber. Can't pass the exception from one custom function to another. When you catch the exception in getOracleSingleValue you can return and string with an error message telling your SKUbyPO function that an error occurred.